# what is data structure? simple straight forward explaination required

Tags: data-structures

i have to explain what data structure is to someone, so what would be the easiest way to explain it? would it be right if i say 
"Data structure is used to organize data(arrange data in some fashion) so that we can perform certain operation fastly with as little resource usage as possible"

Comment: What is there about Wikipedia's definition of *data structure* that is inadequate for your purposes ?  Other definitions are easily available from other online sources too -- why would anyone write another one here ?

Answer (score -1):

How values are placed in locations together and their location addresses and indices are stored as values too.

And that as very abstract "structures" so one has linked lists, arrays, pointers, graphs, binary trees. And can do things with them (the algorithms). The capabilities like being sorted, needing sortedness, fast access and so on.

> This is fundamental, not too complicated, and a good grasp of data
>   structures, the correct usage of data structures can solve problems
>   elegantly. For learning data structures a language like Pascal is more
>   beneficial than C.

Answer (score -1):

In computer science, a data structure is a particular way of organizing data in a computer so that it can be used efficiently.
Source: wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)

I would say what you wrote is pretty close. :)